# How can I write this lambda closure in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to recreate this popular jQuery lambda closure with CoffeeScript:

```
(function($, window, undefined){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
  });
})(jQuery, window);
```

So far I have this:

```
(($, window, undefined) ->
  $ ->
    alert "js!"
)(jQuery, window)
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Parse error on line 1: Unexpected 'BOOL'

It looks like `undefined` is the cause of the problem here. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`undefined` is a keyword in CoffeeScript. You don't need to ensure it's properly defined, so you can forget that part.

CoffeeScript provides a `do` keyword that you can use to create a closure instead of using the immediately-invoked function expression syntax.

CoffeeScript Source <sup>[try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:do%20%28$%20=%20jQuery,%20window%29%20-%3E%20%20%0A%20%20$%20-%3E%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%27jQuery%20ready!%27%0A)</sup>

```
do ($ = jQuery, window) ->  
  $ ->  
    alert "js!"
```

Compiled JavaScript

```
(function($, window) {
  return $(function() {
    return console.log("js!");
  });
})(jQuery, window);
```

The above syntax wasn't supported until CoffeeScript 1.3.1. For older version you still need to do this:

CoffeeScript Source <sup>[[try it]](http://coffeescript.org/#try:((%24%2C%20window)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22js!%22%0A)(jQuery%2C%20window))</sup>

```
(($, window) ->
  $ ->
    alert "js!"
)(jQuery, window)
```

---

If you're curious, here's how CoffeeScript handles `undefined`.

CoffeeScript Source <sup>[[try it]](http://coffeescript.org/#try:console.log%20undefined)</sup>

```
console.log undefined
```

Compiled JavaScript

```
console.log(void 0);
```

You can see that it doesn't use the `undefined` variable, but instead uses [JavaScript's `void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#void) to produce the undefined value.

Answer (score 13):

```
do ($, window) ->
  $ ->
    alert "js!"
```

compiles to

```
(function($, window) {
  return $(function() {
    return alert("js!");
  });
})($, window);
```

Comment: I'm looking to get the `undefined` arg in my func signature. I know this is not critical, but why won't coffeescript let me do it?

Comment: because as the other answer says coffeescript compiles the word `undefined` to `void 0` and does not rely on that variable

Comment: @naomi It's a keyword. What is the purpose of having `undefined` in the function signature? CoffeeScript should eliminate the need for it.

Comment: @Jeremy Blanks, it guarantees that `undefined` will behave as javascript undefined. As I said, I guess it's not necessary but thanks to your answer, now I know why :)

Comment: @naomi that's what coffeescript fixes by making undefined a reserved word.  That way you don't have to do it!